# Replacing a C API dll with C# DLL without affecting clients

Tags: c#, c, interface

I have a **C** DLL, which is an API which exposes many methods.  I want to replace this DLL with one written in a more up to date language.  However, I have customers who have integrated to the **C** DLL already, and I want to just give them the new C# DLL which replicates the **C** DLL.  I need to do this in such a way as the customers who have integrated to the **C** DLL are not affected at all.  i.e. I just want to replace the **C** DLL with the C# one, and it should seem seamless to them.

Is this technically feasible?  And if so, how should I go about replicating the **C** interface in C#.

I have a number of methods in the **C** DLL is defined with dllexport:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void __stdcall
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a C# dll. You would have to write a COM wrapper for the managed dll, and client code would then have to link against the COM wrapper's type library (*.tlb).

You could do that with C++/CLI, by building a mixed-mode dll that exposes the native interface to unmanaged code. Then you would just distribute the dll and the .lib file like normal, and client code would just link against the .lib file (as it presumably does now).

That's a fair bit of work, though. Unless there is some problem with the original C dll, I don't think I would go to the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a DLL written in C language with "a more up-to-date language" is possible.

The questions you need to ask yourself are:

- Do you have the source code for the DLL written in C?
- Do you have test coverage for C API exported from the DLL?
- Do you have C API behavior documented?
- Do you have C API performance and memory consumption details?

If your answer to any of those questions is "no", then I am afraid you won't be able to reliably re-create the functionality in another language.

If you do have all the pre-requisites, then it is relatively trivial to do so — the only cost is your time spent writing, documenting, and testing.

You can create native DLL exports for use from other languages in .Net Framework using say [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) NuGet package. Writing static functions and decorating them with `[DllExport]` and `[MarshalAsAttribute]` where needed is all you need to do.

This of course assumes that you are fluent in both C and C#, and that you have good understanding of memory layouts, stack, ABIs, calling conventions, and datatypes in both languages. Depending on the size of the original DLL this could range from trivial to monumental undertaking for little to no gain except the warm fuzzy feeling of "using an up-to-date language", and could actually decrease the performance and introduce unwanted (or worse yet, unmet) dependencies for the original C DLL clients.

My final advice therefore is "if it ain't broken, don't fix it" unless you want to attempt it as a learning exercise in which case you should start with something less ambitious than a project others rely on.